# Plot with japanese characters in MATLAB 2014b

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-hg2

MATLAB 2014b is using a new graphic environment (HG2) and I was not able to display japanese characters on my plots.
For example the code below does not display the japanese character correctly. I remember to have read before the release that HG2 would support foreign languages. Do I need to set something ? In the previous graphic environment, I did not have any problem with it.

```
plot(1)
title('日本')
```

Comment: Are you sure that new default axes font also supports japanese characters?

Comment: Before the release I saw this feature on the Mathworks website but I am not able to find it anymore. It may have been deleted but it is odd because the previous environment (HG1?) did support it without any additionnal settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What OS are you using? I just tried using R2014b on GLNXA64 and WIN64 and it seemed to work fine for me:

[image: Screenshot on GLNXA64]
[image: Screenshot on WIN64]

Perhaps you need to contact MathWorks technical support.

Comment: I don't really understand, it did not work when I have posted my question and now it seems to work ...